# Windows : Create directory with permission to my process only (C++)

Tags: c++, windows

Create a folder with access granted only to the executing process. The process will delete the data when job is done.

The purpose is to avoid having any other process attempt to manipulate the data in the folder, while the owner process is running.

I already tried giving ACLs and it did not solve the purpose. Basically the current user gets the permission and so if any other process is running under the same user then the other process gets the permissions as well.

// I used the second parameter here to add ACLs

```
CreateDirectory(lpPath, &sa);
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service. Please show your efforts.

Comment: You cannot. Permissions aren’t based on processes, they’re based on users. Run the program on a separate user.

Comment: @Sami, you are saying that there is no way that a process can have a folder private to itself ?

Comment: what is the point of creating a directory when nobody can access it?

Comment: The executing process wishes to keep data which should not be tempered during execution. At the end the process deletes the folder.

Comment: What would happen when the process ends? Nothing could access the files. Permissions are per user (or SID more precisely)

Comment: When process ends the folder gets deleted.

Comment: You way you already tried ACLs. What permissions did you apply, and what did you use to test if they worked? What didn't work about them? Are you able to achieve what you want with a simple script that creates a directory and sets the permissions you want?

Comment: I tried setting GENERIC_ALL | STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL | SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL ; And all these didn't work as the process was runnging under my user and any other process running under my user could make the changes into the folder.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, ACL are used to manage *user* permissions, not process permissions. It is easy in Windows to limit a *file* to a running process by opening it with `CreateFile` with a dwShareMode of 0.

But according to the MSDN page on [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it is possible to get a directory handle with that function if the dwFlagsAndAttributes parameter contains `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS`. Creation is not possible that way, but maybe keeping the directory open could prevent other processes to access it. Beware I have never tested that.

Anyway, I cannot imagine a real use case where it would be required. If you want to do that for security reasons, the correct way is to use a dedicated user. In addition it allows an administrator to control what happens in the directory. And if it is for synchronization reasons, you should rely on standard synchronization primitives